# How to install wkhtmltopdf for docker

Tags: docker, wkhtmltopdf

I'm using [wkhtmltopdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wkhtmltopdf) for nodejs, followed instructions for windows installation (and added it to PATH after installation). When i start my app through bash, it works just fine as it should. I manage to convert html to pdf.

But it doesnt work when im using docker, like it doesnt even exists. Im assuming  there is some other way to install it for docker, or some way to add PATH to docker?? Any other ideas? hints? 
And before u say it, been googling it and looking for images and installations for docker, none helped. Got one that u know it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyways for all the others that found themselves in the same pickle... I was trying to use wkhtmltopdf within docker container while wkhtmltopdf was only installed and executable within system (windows/linux) environment and not in the actual docker environment... after updating dockerfile to automatically install wkhtml with the build, I also had to SET THE PATH.. for linux docker smth like this

> cp wkhtmltox/bin/* /usr/local/bin/ &&

that made everything works just as it should.

Comment: Your original question appears totally valid. Even though today I want to spam profanities at another user though, I held back. I'd recommend not using the answer as a platform to get back at anyone even random unknown people because it makes us "underlings" look bad on the platform. I've certainly been made to feel that way sometimes on here as well and I feel your pain. Keep rockin! ANd if you want to bring up an issue, you should totally visit the Meta forum! People are addressing these issues t here and I think it's working... I think. :D @kerim092

Comment: @Kerim092 How you done it on Windows container?